# Trying to compile Asterisk under Windows with cygwin, unable to find libuuid

Tags: c, windows, gcc, cygwin, asterisk

I want to build Asterisk PBX under Windows, it seems to be possible by using cygwin.

The configure script complains about not finding the uuid_generate_random method in the uuid library.

So I tried to create a little test program :

```
#include <uuid/uuid.h>

int main ()
{
    uuid_t out;
    uuid_generate_random(out);
    return 0;
}
```

This program is compiled using this command : gcc uuid.c -luuid

The -luuid seems to works, as if I change this value (like -luuidX) gcc complains about the fact it can't find the uuidX library.

But the LD pass doesn't works :

```
$ gcc uuid.c -luuid
/tmp/ccu0oh9q.o:uuid.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `uuid_generate_random'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I manage to work around, but this is not really clean, and I don't know how to make the configure script take this tweak :

```
gcc -o uuid.exe uuid.o /cygdrive/c/cygwin/lib/libuuid.dll.a
```

Any idea where does the problem come from ?

Thanks.

Added : verbose gcc output

```
gcc -v uuid.c -luuid
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: i686-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-5.3.0-4.i686/src/gcc-5.3.0/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-5.3.0-4.i686/src/gcc-5.3.0 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --htmldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=i686-pc-cygwin --host=i686-pc-cygwin --target=i686-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,java,lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libcilkrts --enable-libgomp --enable-libitm --enable-libquadmath --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-libjava --enable-libgcj-sublibs --disable-java-awt --disable-symvers --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-prefix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id --with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.3.0 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/cc1.exe -quiet -v -Dunix -idirafter /usr/lib/../include/w32api -idirafter /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/lib/../../include/w32api uuid.c -quiet -dumpbase uuid.c -mtune=generic -march=i686 -auxbase uuid -version -o /tmp/ccVIcgnD.s
GNU C11 (GCC) version 5.3.0 (i686-pc-cygwin)
        compiled by GNU C version 5.3.0, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/lib/../../include/w32api"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/include
 /usr/include
 /usr/lib/../include/w32api
End of search list.
GNU C11 (GCC) version 5.3.0 (i686-pc-cygwin)
        compiled by GNU C version 5.3.0, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: f4218c97435c4e66cb956a0e671020d7
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/as.exe -v -o /tmp/cc0dlffC.o /tmp/ccVIcgnD.s
GNU assembler version 2.25.2 (i686-pc-cygwin) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.25.2
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/:/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/lib/:/usr/lib/:/lib/:/usr/lib/w32api/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=i686'
 /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/collect2.exe -plugin /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/cyglto_plugin.dll -plugin-opt=/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/ccFo5pxm.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lcygwin -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --build-id --wrap _Znwj --wrap _Znaj --wrap _ZdlPv --wrap _ZdaPv --wrap _ZnwjRKSt9nothrow_t --wrap _ZnajRKSt9nothrow_t --wrap _ZdlPvRKSt9nothrow_t --wrap _ZdaPvRKSt9nothrow_t -Bdynamic --dll-search-prefix=cyg --large-address-aware --tsaware /usr/lib/crt0.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0 -L/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/../../../../i686-pc-cygwin/lib -L/usr/lib/w32api /tmp/cc0dlffC.o -luuid -lgcc_s -lgcc -lcygwin -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lgcc_s -lgcc /usr/lib/default-manifest.o /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/5.3.0/crtend.o
/tmp/cc0dlffC.o:uuid.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `uuid_generate_random'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: `gcc  uuid.c -luuid` works for me. Try `gcc -v uuid.c -luuid` to see wich options are not matching.

Comment: Thanks @matzeri, I've modified my question.

Comment: I correct myself. It works on 64 bit but fails on 32bit. I suggest to rise the question on the cygwin mailing list. `https://cygwin.com/cygwin/lists.html` It seems a package error.

Comment: i highly not recommend you use asterisk under Cygwin. If you still want run it under windows, use vmware player. Will be much less issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a gcc package error. As workaround use

```
gcc  uuid.c -luuid -L/usr/lib
```

Reported to cygwin mailing list

https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2016-04/msg00594.html

Comment: Thank you ! Great reply and great job ;)